# How do I make ModsStudio2Previewer.exe access Desktop runtime?

Tags: .net

I have installed .NET framework 7 and 8, but the application insist I should install .NET Desktop runtime,

This is the result of running dotnet --info on cmd

.NET SDK:
Version:           8.0.101
Commit:            6eceda187b
Workload version:  8.0.100-manifests.69afb982

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     Windows
OS Version:  10.0.22621
OS Platform: Windows
RID:         win-x64
Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.101\

.NET workloads installed:
Workload version: 8.0.100-manifests.69afb982
There are no installed workloads to display.

Host:
Version:      8.0.1
Architecture: x64
Commit:       bf5e279d92

.NET SDKs installed:
7.0.405 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:
None

Environment variables:
Not set

global.json file:
Not found

Learn more:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

Comment: There is no ".NET framework 7".

Comment: What do these two lines mean?
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]